# HttpURLConnection won't work after pausing on activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, httpurlconnection

I have an Activity that uses a ListView to display an array of data fetched from a JSON response. Clicking on one of the items will present the user with a business card activity, displaying the data associated with the item clicked. When the application first loads, it works fine. I can close the business card and reopen it multiple times. However, if i pause on the ListView activity, the page will no longer load the data. I have placed Log.d commands before and after the connection to try debugging the issue. The activity is receiving the information necessary to perform the connection. However, the closest I have gotten to a solution is knowing that when it doesn't work, I cannot Log.d the response code immediately after opening the connection.

To be clear, I am including the entirety of the code I am using, just in case the issue lies somewhere else. First is the code for the ListView Activity, then is the Business Card Activity code.

This is the Directory Activity.

```
    public class DirectoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lvContacts;
    Button goMenu;
    Button goFilter;
    TextView tempText;

    static ArrayList<String> arrlst = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    private FetchList process;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_directory);

    lvContacts = findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);
    goMenu = findViewById(R.id.btn_goMenu);
    goFilter = findViewById(R.id.btn_goSearch);
    tempText = findViewById(R.id.temptext);

    // Set adapter for listview: used in FetchList
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.layout_org_list, R.id.listViewItem, arrlst );
    lvContacts.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Get list from DB
    process = new FetchList();
    process.setListener(new FetchList.FetchListTaskListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFetchListTaskFinished(String[] result) {
            // update UI in Activity here
            arrlst.clear();
            for (String OrgName:result) {
                addItemsToList(OrgName);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    process.execute();

    // Set onclick listener for listview
    lvContacts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String selectedOrg = lvContacts.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); // Get org name from list view
            goBusinessCard(selectedOrg); // Go to business card
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    process.setListener(null); // PREVENT LEAK AFTER ACTIVITY DESTROYED
    super.onDestroy();
}

public static void addItemsToList(String item) {
    arrlst.add(item);
}

// Set Methods for Buttons
public void goMenu(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
}

public void goFilter(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, FilterActivity.class));
    Log.d("FILTER DEBUG", "checking if extras are filled " + this.getIntent().getExtras());
}

// Method for opening BusinessCardActivity and passes orgID
public void goBusinessCard(String selectedOrg) {
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.clear();
    extras.putString("selectedOrg", selectedOrg);
    Intent BusinessCard = new Intent(this, BusinessCardActivity.class);
    BusinessCard.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(BusinessCard);
}

    // ASYNC TASK
static class FetchList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {
    private FetchListTaskListener listener;

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL(URL_READ_ORG ); // Set url to API Call location
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open connection to html
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream(); // create input stream from html location
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8")); // create reader for inputStream

            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                data.append(line); // creates string from all lines in response
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            JSONObject JO = new JSONObject(data.toString()); // creates object from json response in data string
            JSONArray JA = JO.getJSONArray("orgs");

            // Create array list to store items from json response
            List<String> al_orgList = new ArrayList<>();

            // Iterate through JSON array to get json object org_name
            for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject Orgs = JA.getJSONObject(i);
                String org_name = Orgs.getString("org_name");
                al_orgList.add(org_name);
            }

            // convert array list to array
            return al_orgList.toArray(new String[al_orgList.size()]);

        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    // UI Process - allows manipulation of UI
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onFetchListTaskFinished(result);
        }
    }

    private void setListener(FetchListTaskListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface FetchListTaskListener {
        void onFetchListTaskFinished(String[] result);
    }

}
```

This is the Business Card Activity that runs the data fetch for individual items

```
    public class BusinessCardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv_org, tv_name, tv_email, tv_phone, tv_website, tv_servicetype,
        tv_servicesprovided, tv_address;
    String Favorite, Latitude, Longitude, selectedOrg, FavoriteChanged, dbPhone, phoneNum, dbWeb, orgWeb;
    CheckBox cbFavorite;

    List<String> arrlstID = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] arrID;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_business_card);

    // Assign fields to variables
    tv_org = findViewById(R.id.tv_org);
    tv_name = findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    tv_email = findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
    tv_phone = findViewById(R.id.tv_phone);
    tv_website = findViewById(R.id.tv_website);
    tv_servicetype = findViewById(R.id.tv_servicetype);
    tv_servicesprovided = findViewById(R.id.tv_servicesprovided);
    tv_address = findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
    cbFavorite = findViewById(R.id.cbFavorite);

    // Set variable for selectedOrg from DirectoryActivity
    selectedOrg = Objects.requireNonNull(this.getIntent().getExtras()).getString("selectedOrg");

    // Get Org data from DB using async
    process = new FetchOrg();
    process.setListener(new FetchOrg.FetchOrgTaskListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFetchOrgTaskFinished(String[] result) {
            setTextView(result);

            // onClick for Email
            tv_email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    showEmailDialog();
                }
            });

            // onClick for Call
            tv_phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Get phone number from DB
                    // Replace any non-digit in phone number to make call
                    phoneNum = dbPhone.replaceAll("\\D", "");

                    // make call
                    goCall(phoneNum);
                }
            });

            // onClick for Web
            tv_website.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Fix URL logic
                    orgWeb = "http://" + dbWeb;
                    goWeb(orgWeb);
                }
            });

            // onClick for Address
            tv_address.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    goMap();
                }
            });

            // TODO add favorite functionality
            // When checkbox status changes, change value of Favorite
            cbFavorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
    process.execute(selectedOrg);


    /*
    // if favorite = 1 then check box
    if (Favorite.equals("1")) {
        cbFavorite.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        cbFavorite.setChecked(false);
    }
    */
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    process.setListener(null); // PREVENT LEAK AFTER ACTIVITY DESTROYED
    super.onDestroy();
}


// Method to assign text view items from async task
public void setTextView(String[] org_data) {

    String name = org_data[1] + " " + org_data[2];
    String address = org_data[8] + " " + org_data[9] + " " + org_data[10] + " " + org_data[11];

    tv_org.setText(org_data[0]);
    tv_name.setText(name);
    tv_email.setText(org_data[3]);
    tv_phone.setText(org_data[4]);
    tv_website.setText(org_data[5]);
    tv_servicetype.setText(org_data[6]);
    tv_servicesprovided.setText(org_data[7]);
    tv_address.setText(address);
}

public void showEmailDialog() {
    // Get dialog_box_goals.xml view
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(BusinessCardActivity.this);
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_box_send_email, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BusinessCardActivity.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

    final EditText etEmailMessage = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.etMailMessage);

    // setup a dialog window
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)

            .setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // my code

                /* WONT USE THIS UNTIL EMAILS ARE FINAL
                   USING MY EMAIL FOR TESTING PURPOSES
                    // Get email
                    niagaraDB.open();
                    c2 = niagaraDB.getEmailByID(passedID);
                    if (c2.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        public String emailTo = c2.getString(0);
                    }
                    niagaraDB.close();
                */

                    // This is for final code
                    // String to = "mailto:" + emailTo;
                    String to = "snownwakendirt@yahoo.com";
                    String subject = "Mail From Connect & Protect Niagara App";
                    String message = etEmailMessage.getText().toString();

                    if (message.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(BusinessCardActivity.this,
                                "Message must contain something",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { to });
                        // email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to});
                        // email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});
                        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

                        // need this to prompt email client only
                        email.setType("message/rfc822");

                        try {
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
                            finish();
                            Log.i("Email Sent...", "");
                        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                            Toast.makeText(BusinessCardActivity.this,
                                    "There is no email client installed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // create an alert dialog
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}

public void goCall(final String phoneNum) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phoneNum, null)));
}

public void goWeb(String orgWeb) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(orgWeb)));
}

public void goCloseBusinessCard(View v) {
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, DirectoryActivity.class));
}

public void goMap() {
    /*
      int locationAddressLatInt = Integer.parseInt(locationAddressLat);
      int locationAddressLongInt = Integer.parseInt(locationAddressLong);
     */

    // pass id to map view. only one item in array for ease of use in MapActivity
    arrlstID.add(selectedOrg);
    arrID = new String[arrlstID.size()];
    arrlstID.toArray(arrID);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putStringArray("arrID", arrID);
    Intent Map = new Intent(BusinessCardActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
    Map.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(Map);
}


// ASYNC TASK
static class FetchOrg extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
    private FetchOrgTaskListener listener;

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            // assign passed string from main thread
            String org_name = params[0];
            String orgbyname = URL_GET_ORG_BY_NAME + "?org_name=" + org_name;
            String line = "";

            URL url = new URL(orgbyname);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"));

                line = br.readLine();

                br.close();
                is.close();
                conn.disconnect();


        /*
            This JSON section contains a JSON Object that holds a JSON Array. The Array is created to
            individualize each object within the JSON Array. Then, each JSON object is fetched and
            assigned to a string variable.
         */
            JSONObject JO = new JSONObject(line); // creates object from json response in data string
            JSONObject Orgs = JO.getJSONObject("orgs"); // creates array for parsing of json data

            // get items from JSONArray and assign for passing to onProgressUpdate
            String Org = Orgs.getString("org_name");
            String FirstName = Orgs.getString("contact_first_name");
            String LastName = Orgs.getString("contact_last_name");
            String Email = Orgs.getString("contact_email");
            String Phone = Orgs.getString("contact_phone");
            String Website = Orgs.getString("org_website");
            String ServiceType = Orgs.getString("org_type");
            String ServicesProvided = Orgs.getString("org_services");
            String Address = Orgs.getString("org_street_address");
            String City = Orgs.getString("org_city");
            String State = Orgs.getString("org_state");
            String Zip = Orgs.getString("org_zip");
            String Lat = Orgs.getString("latitude");
            String Long = Orgs.getString("longitude");

            // Add items to string array
            String[] org_data = new String[14]; // 14 is length of array, not the count
            org_data[0] = Org;
            org_data[1] = FirstName;
            org_data[2] = LastName;
            org_data[3] = Email;
            org_data[4] = Phone;
            org_data[5] = Website;
            org_data[6] = ServiceType;
            org_data[7] = ServicesProvided;
            org_data[8] = Address;
            org_data[9] = City;
            org_data[10] = State;
            org_data[11] = Zip;
            org_data[12] = Lat;
            org_data[13] = Long;

            return org_data;

        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onFetchOrgTaskFinished(result);
        }
    }

    private void setListener(FetchOrgTaskListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface FetchOrgTaskListener {
        void onFetchOrgTaskFinished(String[] result);
    }
}
```

Comment: The MCVE required by SO begins with minimal. Just the code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please clarify "...if i pause on the ListView activity, the page will no longer load the data..."?  What do you mean by "pause" ? And when do you pause?

Comment: @Barns When the application loads, i can click on the listview items and navigate then to the business card activity. when i close the business card activity, it goes back to the listview. if i wait to the count of 5, then click another item, the business card activity loads without loading any of the data from the httpurlconnection

Answer (score 0):

Activity lifecycle would go back from paused to resume state. 
You need to provide the expected behaviour inside onResume something like below

```
public void onResume(){ 
    super.onResume(); 
      new XXXAsyncTask( new XXXAsyncListener(){ 
      public void postTaskMethod(){ 
     //do stuff here 
     } 
    }).execute(); 
    }
```

Comment: With a well designed app there is no need to trigger another download with a relatively static dataset. This will just unnecessarily add to data usage.

Comment: @Barns I totally agree. I am working on a prototype for a project that I need to present to the city of Niagara Falls at the end of the month. Ideally, I want to use a connection to clone a database from a server to the phone, but I don't have time to implement that until after the presentation.

Comment: @Rizwan I tried that to no avail. It did not fix the bug. The data will still fail to show if i pause on the listview activity, even after implementing the onResume method.

Comment: @JeffWeber will try again, one confirmation needed when you mention for pause and async misbehavior, you mean FetchOrg or FetchList task?

Comment: @Rizwan the issue is with the FetchOrg task on the BusinessCardActivity. The data does not show if I navigate to the DirectoryActivity, wait 5 seconds, then click on an item to navigate to the BusinessCardActivity again.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes in your `onCreate()`method of your `BusinessCardActivity`. I check for `hasExtra` instead--a little more flexibility. I got rid of the `Listener` and packed all `onClick` listener below. I felt it was a bit too complicated using the `Listener` approach (So you can remove this `process.setListener(null);` from the `onDestroy()`method). I also added a few `Log.e();` so you can see what is going on in the logcat.

(BTW "TAG"  would be:

`private static final Strting TAG = BusinessCardActivity.class.getSimpleName();`)

With "BusinessCardActivity.class.getSimpleName();"  written out just in case you refactor sometime.

This is part of your `BusinessCardActivity` `onCreate()` method:

```
// Set variable for selectedOrg from DirectoryActivity
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
if(intent.hasExtra(selectedOrg)){
    String selectedOrg = intent.getStringExtra("selectedOrg")
    Log.e(TAG, "selectedOrg : " + selectedOrg);
    FetchOrg process = new FetchOrg();
    process.execute(selectedOrg);
}
else{
    Log.e(TAG, "No Extras!")
    //You might what to call finish() here
    return;
}

//Move all your onClick Listeners below...
```

I don't think this is the best case to use a `Listener` so lets use the `AsyncTask` like this (I also removed the `static`):

```
class FetchOrg extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground ... Started");
            // assign passed string from main thread
            String org_name = params[0];
            String orgbyname = URL_GET_ORG_BY_NAME + "?org_name=" + org_name;
            String line = "";

            URL url = new URL(orgbyname);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"));

                line = br.readLine();

                br.close();
                is.close();
                conn.disconnect();

            Log.e(TAG, "Data Returned : " + line);

        /*
            This JSON section contains a JSON Object that holds a JSON Array. The Array is created to
            individualize each object within the JSON Array. Then, each JSON object is fetched and
            assigned to a string variable.
         */
            JSONObject JO = new JSONObject(line); // creates object from json response in data string
            JSONObject Orgs = JO.getJSONObject("orgs"); // creates array for parsing of json data

            // get items from JSONArray and assign for passing to onProgressUpdate
            String Org = Orgs.getString("org_name");
            String FirstName = Orgs.getString("contact_first_name");
            String LastName = Orgs.getString("contact_last_name");
            String Email = Orgs.getString("contact_email");
            String Phone = Orgs.getString("contact_phone");
            String Website = Orgs.getString("org_website");
            String ServiceType = Orgs.getString("org_type");
            String ServicesProvided = Orgs.getString("org_services");
            String Address = Orgs.getString("org_street_address");
            String City = Orgs.getString("org_city");
            String State = Orgs.getString("org_state");
            String Zip = Orgs.getString("org_zip");
            String Lat = Orgs.getString("latitude");
            String Long = Orgs.getString("longitude");

            // Add items to string array
            String[] org_data = new String[14]; // 14 is length of array, not the count
            org_data[0] = Org;
            org_data[1] = FirstName;
            org_data[2] = LastName;
            org_data[3] = Email;
            org_data[4] = Phone;
            org_data[5] = Website;
            org_data[6] = ServiceType;
            org_data[7] = ServicesProvided;
            org_data[8] = Address;
            org_data[9] = City;
            org_data[10] = State;
            org_data[11] = Zip;
            org_data[12] = Lat;
            org_data[13] = Long;

            return org_data;

        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        setTextView(result);
    }
}
```

Also I would change your method `goBusinessCard()` a bit (and no need to be public):

```
private void goBusinessCard(String selectedOrg) {
    //Java variables should written in lower case and Classes Capitalized
    Intent businessCard = new Intent(this, BusinessCardActivity.class);
    businessCard.putExtra("selectedOrg", selectedOrg);
    startActivity(businessCard);
}
```

**Please let me know if you have any issues! I typed this out in a standard Text Editor..so there might be a few typos.**

Comment: Thank you so much for all that! However, this method is throwing the "No Extras!" log. It looks right and there are no errors flagging on android studio.

Also, you removed static from the AsyncTask but that is telling me it should be static or leaks might occur?

Comment: @JeffWeber :: static?  I have never had that with `AsyncTask`. "No Extras!" ?    Did you change your `goBusinessCard()` card as I described?

Comment: i swear! it isnt keeping the program from running but it tells me that memory leaks may occur. and yes, i did change the goBusinessCard(). If i go back to the way i retrieved the extras, it works with the bug. but switching to the method you used (which i like better) it tells me that there are no extras

Comment: the edits including the information you requested should be visible now. If it helps, i can also send the debug text, but when the bug happens, it literally displays nothing, so it may not be useful

Comment: @JeffWeber :: Perhaps the problem is that I wrote `intent.hasExtra(selectedOrg)`  instead of `intent.hasExtra("selectedOrg")`

Comment: Well, that was the problem with the extras! But the bug still persists unfortunately.

Comment: @JeffWeber :: So the code goes through the `hasExtras` and triggers `process.execute(selectedOrg);`?  Does "doInBackground ... Started" and "Data Returned : " (including the returned data) show up in the log?

Comment: It is triggered yes. Similar to before, if i dont wait and click an item immediately, it will display the correct information. However, "doInBackground ... Started" and "Data Returned:" only show up when the bug hasn't been triggered yet. They do display if I don't wait, but when i return to the list and pause for the 5 second minimum, and click another item, it doesn't display either. BUT, "selectedOrg : " does display the item that was selected in both cases, if that helps

Comment: update: I tried it again, and it did display that doInBackground started one time during the bug, then i tried again and it did not display the second time.

Comment: @JeffWeber :: This is indeed odd behavior. I will look into it further. It will probably take some time--probably tomorrow before I have anything.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been researching and testing and debugging for 2 weeks and finally resorted to asking for help. No rush, but time is of the essence so i truly do appreciate your help! If i could give you more than thanks, I would! Ill keep my eyes open for a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Posting a new answer so I can add all the code for the `BusinessCardActivity` class.

I added some additional logging and changed `getString()` to `optString()` in order to be able to offer an alternative value. For example if the value or "key"  is invalid or missing you would get an error.

public class BusinessCardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    TextView tv_org, tv_name, tv_email, tv_phone, tv_website, tv_servicetype,
        tv_servicesprovided, tv_address;
    String Favorite, Latitude, Longitude, FavoriteChanged, dbPhone, phoneNum, dbWeb, orgWeb;
    CheckBox cbFavorite;

    List<String> arrlstID = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] arrID;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_business_card);

    // Assign fields to variables
    tv_org = findViewById(R.id.tv_org);
    tv_name = findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    tv_email = findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
    tv_phone = findViewById(R.id.tv_phone);
    tv_website = findViewById(R.id.tv_website);
    tv_servicetype = findViewById(R.id.tv_servicetype);
    tv_servicesprovided = findViewById(R.id.tv_servicesprovided);
    tv_address = findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
    cbFavorite = findViewById(R.id.cbFavorite);


    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    if(!intent.hasExtra("selectedOrg")){
        Log.e(TAG, "No Extras!")
        //You might what to call finish() here
        return;
    }

        String selectedOrg = intent.getStringExtra("selectedOrg")
        Log.e(TAG, "selectedOrg : " + selectedOrg);
        FetchOrg process = new FetchOrg();
        process.execute(selectedOrg);

        // onClick for Email
        tv_email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    showEmailDialog();
                }
            });

            // onClick for Call
            tv_phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Get phone number from DB
                    // Replace any non-digit in phone number to make call
                    phoneNum = dbPhone.replaceAll("\\D", "");

                    // make call
                    goCall(phoneNum);
                }
            });

            // onClick for Web
            tv_website.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Fix URL logic
                    orgWeb = "http://" + dbWeb;
                    goWeb(orgWeb);
                }
            });

            // onClick for Address
            tv_address.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    goMap();
                }
            });

            // TODO add favorite functionality
            // When checkbox status changes, change value of Favorite
            cbFavorite.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                }
            });


    /*
    // if favorite = 1 then check box
    if (Favorite.equals("1")) {
        cbFavorite.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        cbFavorite.setChecked(false);
    }
    */
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    process.setListener(null); // PREVENT LEAK AFTER ACTIVITY DESTROYED
    super.onDestroy();
}


// Method to assign text view items from async task
public void setTextView(String[] org_data) {

    String name = org_data[1] + " " + org_data[2];
    String address = org_data[8] + " " + org_data[9] + " " + org_data[10] + " " + org_data[11];

    tv_org.setText(org_data[0]);
    tv_name.setText(name);
    tv_email.setText(org_data[3]);
    tv_phone.setText(org_data[4]);
    tv_website.setText(org_data[5]);
    tv_servicetype.setText(org_data[6]);
    tv_servicesprovided.setText(org_data[7]);
    tv_address.setText(address);
}

public void showEmailDialog() {
    // Get dialog_box_goals.xml view
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(BusinessCardActivity.this);
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_box_send_email, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BusinessCardActivity.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

    final EditText etEmailMessage = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.etMailMessage);

    // setup a dialog window
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)

            .setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // my code

                /* WONT USE THIS UNTIL EMAILS ARE FINAL
                   USING MY EMAIL FOR TESTING PURPOSES
                    // Get email
                    niagaraDB.open();
                    c2 = niagaraDB.getEmailByID(passedID);
                    if (c2.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        public String emailTo = c2.getString(0);
                    }
                    niagaraDB.close();
                */

                    // This is for final code
                    // String to = "mailto:" + emailTo;
                    String to = "snownwakendirt@yahoo.com";
                    String subject = "Mail From Connect & Protect Niagara App";
                    String message = etEmailMessage.getText().toString();

                    if (message.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(BusinessCardActivity.this,
                                "Message must contain something",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { to });
                        // email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to});
                        // email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});
                        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

                        // need this to prompt email client only
                        email.setType("message/rfc822");

                        try {
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
                            finish();
                            Log.i("Email Sent...", "");
                        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                            Toast.makeText(BusinessCardActivity.this,
                                    "There is no email client installed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // create an alert dialog
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}

public void goCall(final String phoneNum) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phoneNum, null)));
}

public void goWeb(String orgWeb) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(orgWeb)));
}

public void goCloseBusinessCard(View v) {
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, DirectoryActivity.class));
}

public void goMap() {
    /*
      int locationAddressLatInt = Integer.parseInt(locationAddressLat);
      int locationAddressLongInt = Integer.parseInt(locationAddressLong);
     */

    // pass id to map view. only one item in array for ease of use in MapActivity
    arrlstID.add(selectedOrg);
    arrID = new String[arrlstID.size()];
    arrlstID.toArray(arrID);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putStringArray("arrID", arrID);
    Intent Map = new Intent(BusinessCardActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
    Map.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(Map);
}


// ASYNC TASK
class FetchOrg extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        String[] org_data = null;
        try {
            Log.e(TAG, "FetchOrg doInBackground started");

            // assign passed string from main thread
            String org_name = params[0];
            String orgbyname = URL_GET_ORG_BY_NAME + "?org_name=" + org_name;

            URL url = new URL(orgbyname);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            Log.e(TAG, "FetchOrg doInBackground Connected!");


            //Check the response code of the server -
            Integer replyCode = con.getResponseCode();
            logMess += "   Reply Code:  " + replyCode.toString();

            responseStream = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));

            stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
            logMess += "   elapsed Time :  " + elapsedTime + " ms";

            Log.e(TAG, "FetchOrg logMess:  --- " + logMess);
            String line = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            //Make sure you get everything!
            while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            //this will close underlying streams
            responseStreamReader.close();

            String data = stringBuilder.toString();
            Log.e(TAG, "FetchOrg Data:  --- " + data);

        /*
            This JSON section contains a JSON Object that holds a JSON Array. The Array is created to
            individualize each object within the JSON Array. Then, each JSON object is fetched and
            assigned to a string variable.
         */
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data); // creates object from json response in data string
            JSONObject orgs = obj.getJSONObject("orgs"); // creates array for parsing of json data

            String nA = "not available";

            // get items from JSONArray and assign for passing to onProgressUpdate
            String Org = orgs.optString("org_name", nA);
            String FirstName = orgs.optString("contact_first_name", nA);
            String LastName = orgs.optString("contact_last_name", nA);
            String Email = orgs.optString("contact_email", nA);
            String Phone = orgs.optString("contact_phone", nA);
            String Website = orgs.optString("org_website", nA);
            String ServiceType = orgs.optString("org_type", nA);
            String ServicesProvided = orgs.optString("org_services", nA);
            String Address = orgs.optString("org_street_address", nA);
            String City = orgs.optString("org_city", nA);
            String State = orgs.optString("org_state", nA);
            String Zip = orgs.optString("org_zip", nA);
            String Lat = orgs.optString("latitude", nA);
            String Long = orgs.optString("longitude", nA);

            // Add items to string array
            org_data = new String[14]; // 14 is length of array, not the count
            org_data[0] = Org;
            org_data[1] = FirstName;
            org_data[2] = LastName;
            org_data[3] = Email;
            org_data[4] = Phone;
            org_data[5] = Website;
            org_data[6] = ServiceType;
            org_data[7] = ServicesProvided;
            org_data[8] = Address;
            org_data[9] = City;
            org_data[10] = State;
            org_data[11] = Zip;
            org_data[12] = Lat;
            org_data[13] = Long;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "FetchOrg doInBackground: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
            //just in case you get an error above
            if(con != null){
                con.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return org_data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        if(result != null){
            setTextView(result);
        }
        else{
            Log.e(TAG, "FetchOrg onPostExecute: result is null");
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that I did not clean up things like maintaining minimal scope: For example :`public void showEmailDialog()` and `public void goMap()` which do not need to be public methods! Any method that does not need to be accessed outside the class (and that is rare!) should not be made `public`.

You have also defined many class variables at the beginning of the class like "Favorite, Latitude, Longitude, FavoriteChanged" do they need to have class wide scope?? And they are variables! So in java naming convention, variables and methods are written in lower case, while classes are capitalized--this helps reading code easier (for the SO community!)

When working with `Indent` extras often mistakes are made when entering the "key" like "selectedOrg". Therefore it is some times an advantage to create a global class to help keep things straight. Example `public class GlobalExtras` and just keep `public static final String SELECTED_ORG = "selectedOrg";` Then just use `intent.getString(SELECTED_ORG);`

Another thing: I am not a big fan of `String[]` as you have used to store your "org" strings. They can be tricky with size and indexes. You might want to consider using another object.

I do not have access to your API and your data, so I was only able to make requests on my server trying to duplicate your user scenario, but I was unable to reproduce your issue. I hope this helps, let me know what the logcat spits out!

Comment: You're a hero. I am on my way to bed but if it all works and fixes that bug, I'll mark it as answered and give the kudos where it's due! I'll let you know how it goes. You said you reproduced the error?? Did you fix it with these suggestions? I would assume so but I want to be sure. And thank you so much for the pointers. It drives me nuts when code is sloppy, and every lesson I learn in making it better is appreciated!

Comment: @JeffWeber :: unfortunately I was NOT able to reproduce the issue. I do not have access to the server you get your data from...that might be the issue. But I used the code to download other data from the Internet and made a similar case scenario, but I had no issues. :: I added additional logging in the code above..perhaps that will help get a lead to the problem.